# Парсинг ответа сервера yandex-tank-ом

Tags: яндекс-танк

Умеет ли yandex-tank парсить ответ от сервера и отправлять новый запрос с параметром, полученным из ответа сервера?

В документации не нашлось описания такой возможности.

Comment: <offtopic>Тут появились ещё вопросы по вашему тегу.</offtopic>

Answer (score 2):

yandex-tank это обертка над подключаемыми генераторами нагрузки.

Модуль `phantom` генерировать запросы на лету не умеет, но можно подключить  JMeter с сценарием который будет разбирать пришедший ответ.
Опции подключения можно посмотреть в http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#jmeter.

В одном конфиге танка также можно указать одновременно и секцию для фантома и секцию для джметра. Работать они будут независимо, каждый со своим набором данных.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме JMeter можно использовать встроенную в танк [BFG](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#bfg) -- она позволяет писать сценарии стрельб на Python.